# How to apply dynamic range on a filter

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, filter

I'm trying to encode the dynamic range into the filter. However, I'm unsure of how. I want the filter to check if there are any NA's, if there this, then I want to display them. If there are no NA's, then I want the "Select All" filter.

```
Sub SDOIP5()

' SDOIP5 Macro
' It filters the NA in Subcluster
'

Dim LastRow2 As Long
LastRow2 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$BI$196").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Filter Dynamic Range

```
Option Explicit

Sub SDOIP5()
' SDOIP5 Macro
' It filters the NA in Subcluster '
'
    Const CriteriaValue As String = "#N/A"
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim rng As Range
        ' If for any reason 'CurrentRegion' doesn't work for you,
        ' then just define the complete range including the headers.
        Set rng = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        ' To test that you have the right range, uncomment the following line
        ' to write the defined range address to the Immediate window (CTRL+G).
        'Debug.Print rng.Address(0, 0)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                       Criteria1:=CriteriaValue
        With rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If .Rows.Count = 1 And .Areas.Count = 1 Then
                .Parent.ShowAllData
            End If
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

- This will use the `defineEndRange` function to define your range.
- The solution is setup with the first cell `A2`.
- Again, if this doesn't work, you will have to supply the range manually e.g.

  ```
  Set rng = .Range("A2:BI196")
  ```

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SDOIP5()
' SDOIP5 Macro
' It filters the NA in Subcluster '
'
    Const CriteriaValue As String = "#N/A"
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = defineEndRange(.Range("A2"))
        ' To test that you have the right range, uncomment the following line,
        ' to write the defined range address to the Immediate window (CTRL+G).
        Debug.Print rng.Address(0, 0)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                       Criteria1:=CriteriaValue
        With rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If .Rows.Count = 1 And .Areas.Count = 1 Then
                .Parent.ShowAllData
            End If
        End With
    End With

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Defines the range from a specified first cell to the last cell
'               of its Current Region. It is the Current Region minus the cells
'               to the left and above of the specified first cell.
' Remarks:      If the specified first cell is "A1", then its Current Region
'               and its End Range are the same.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function defineEndRange(FirstCellRange As Range) _
         As Range
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "defineEndRange"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    ' Validate First Cell Range.
    If FirstCellRange Is Nothing Then
        GoTo NoFirstCellRange
    End If
    ' Define Current Region ('rng').
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = FirstCellRange.CurrentRegion
    ' Define End Range.
    Set defineEndRange = FirstCellRange _
      .Resize(rng.Rows.Count + rng.Row - FirstCellRange.Row, _
              rng.Columns.Count + rng.Column - FirstCellRange.Column)
    ' Exit.
    GoTo ProcExit
' Labels
NoFirstCellRange:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': No First Cell Range."
    GoTo ProcExit
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo ProcExit
ProcExit:
End Function
```

Comment: @MariaRodriguez: I've added another solution.